# How to transform the first element for all tuples move one place afterwards in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

For example, if I had a list of tuples like: `[('first', 0),('second', 1),('third', 2)]`
I want to transform it to: `[('default', 0),('first', 1),('second', 2)]`

the second column stays the same but the first column which is the first element move one place afterward for all tuples and the first place will be replaced `'default'`.
Is there any quick method to do this?

Comment: What was the difficulty you encountered when you tried to do this?

Comment: You could use pandas or you could loop over the tuples, setting the value in every row. Please try it and ask a _specific_ question about your attempt. Don't forget to include a [mre]! Please also take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One line solution**

```
#l = [('first', 0),('second', 1),('third', 2)]
[('default' if i == 0 else l[i-1][0], y) for i, (_, y) in enumerate(l)]
#[('default', '0'), ('first', '1'), ('second', '2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure Python solution:

```
def shift(in_list):
    out_list = []
    for index, item in enumerate(in_list):
        if index > 0:
            out_list.append((in_list[index-1][0],item[1]))
        else:
            out_list.append(('default',item[1]))
    return out_list

before = [('first', 0),('second', 1),('third', 2)]
after = [('default', 0),('first', 1),('second', 2)]

assert shift(before) == after
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
l = [('first', 0),('second', 1),('third', 2)]
[(x[0], y[1]) for x, y in zip([('default',)] + l[:-1], l)]
```

The result is:

```sh
[('default', 0), ('first', 1), ('second', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure python with no assumptions on content of the tuples

```py
tups = [('first', 0), ('second', 1), ('third', 2)]

transformed = [('default', tups[0][1])] + [(p[0], c[1]) for p, c in zip(tups[:-1], tups[1:])]
print(transformed) # [('default', 0), ('first', 1), ('second', 2)]
```